# Switch signers on an In Process shared document

Tags: docusignapi

Is it possible to switch a signer (with tabs), on a shared document, once an envelope's In Process?

Our process goes like this:

1. A single shared PDF document is generated (not using a DocuSign template) with signing placeholders for all signers.
2. We create and send an envelope for the document PDF.
3. One or more customers sign the document (using an embedded signing page).
4. The last signer (our employee) signs the document (also using an embedded signing page).

The employee signer could be one of several employees, but, whomever it is, they'll always sign the same locations on the document.  We'd like to be able to delay the choice of which employee signs the document until the end of the process, instead having to specify them at envelope creation.

Once the envelope is In Process, I'm able to add and delete employee recipients, but I can't find a way to include their tabs too.  I include the tabs in the request, but the added employee is always in a draft-like 'created' state without tabs.  The embedded view still asks the viewer to manually place their tabs.  I need the tabs to be already placed and locked in position on the document so the employee can sign.

We're using the REST API and this needs to be an automated solution (no manual envelope corrections).  Is there some way to achieve this or something similar?

Here's my add-recipient request

```
POST https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/<account>/envelopes/<envelope-id>/recipients?resend_envelope=true

{
"signers" : [{
        "recipientId" : 4,
        "email" : "john@example.com",
        "name" : "John Citizen",
        "tabs" : {
            "initialHereTabs" : [{
                    "documentId" : "1",
                    "recipientId" : 4,
                    "name" : "InitialHere_3",
                    "pageNumber" : 1,
                    "xPosition" : 282,
                    "yPosition" : 454,
                    "tabName" : "InitialHere_3"
                }
            ],
            "signHereTabs" : [{
                    "documentId" : "1",
                    "recipientId" : 4,
                    "name" : "SignHere_3",
                    "pageNumber" : 1,
                    "xPosition" : 81,
                    "yPosition" : 447,
                    "tabName" : "SignHere_3"
                }
            ],
        },
        "clientUserId" : "LTEST_Resident4",
        "routingOrder" : 2,
    }
]
}
```

(I've also tried the same request with PUT instead of POST.  The result is the same)

Comment: Can you post your Add Employee Request, so we can see what you're donig when attempting already?

Comment: I've added my request.  This is for my simplified proof-of-concept.  The actual documents are a lot more complicated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**It sounds like your workflow needs to do the following:**

1. Create Envelope with a "Blocker Recipient"
2. Add Additional Recipient when they're identified
3. Add Tags to new Recipient
4. Delete "Blocker Recipient" when you want the document sent on

**I'll assume you have 1. taken care of and I'll go through quick examples of 2-4.**

### **2. Create Additional Recipient**

```
POST: https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/recipients

{
    "signers": [
        {
            "email": "email@domain.com",
            "name": "Andrew Wilson",
            "recipientId": "3",
            "defaultRecipient": "true",
            "routingOrder": "3"
        }
    ]
}
```

### **3. Add Tags to Recipient**

```
POST: https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/recipients/{recipientId}/tabs

{
    "signHereTabs": [
        {
            "xPosition": "100",
            "yPosition": "200",
            "documentId": "1",
            "pageNumber": "1"
        },
        {
            "xPosition": "200",
            "yPosition": "200",
            "documentId": "1",
            "pageNumber": "1"
        }
    ]
}
```

### **4. Delete Blocker Recipient**

```
DELETE: https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/recipients/{recipientId}
```

Comment: Success!  Thank you.  The key difference from what I was doing, is that the tabs are added in a separate request.  It seems that Add Recipient doesn't process the tabs in signers, whereas Create Envelope and Modify Recipient both do.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are trying to Modify or Correct and Resend Recipient Information.

https://www.docusign.com/sites/default/files/REST_API_Guide_v2.pdf  Page 137

**Modify or Correct and Resend Recipient Information**

This lets you modify recipients in a draft envelope or correct recipient information for an in process envelope.For draft envelopes, you can edit: email, userName, routingOrder, faxNumber, deliveryMethod,accessCode and requireIdLookup. Once an envelope has been sent, you can only edit: email, userName, signerName, routingOrder,faxNumber, and deliveryMethod.You can also select to resend an envelope by using the resend_envelope option.

**Example Request:**

```
    PUT https://{server}/restapi/{apiVersion}/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/recipients?resend_envelope=true

    X-DocuSign-Authentication:<DocuSignCredentials><Username>{name}</Username><Password>{password}</Password><IntegratorKey>{integrator_key}</IntegratorKey></DocuSignCredentials>
    Accept: application/json
    Content-Type: application/json

    {

    "signers": [
        {
            "email": "email@domain.com",
            "name": "John Smith",
            "recipientId": "1"
        }
    ]
}
```

**Response**

The response returns if the correction was successful.The following example shows the response json body.

**Example Response:**

```
{
    "recipientUpdateResults": [
        {
            "errorDetails": {
                "errorCode": "SUCCESS",
                "message": ""
            },
            "recipientId": "1"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks Justin, I've tried the Modify too (it's the same request but with PUT instead of POST), but it has the same result.  It works fine for _editing_ a signer, but I want to switch to another signer, with a different clientUserId.