# Can you use the Any Signer feature in a (REST API) embedded process?

Tags: docusignapi

I'd like to use the **Any Signer** functionality, but our signing application uses *embedded* signing only.  Can you use Any Signers in an embedded process?

The problem I run up against is that I can only get Any Signer working for non-embedded signers.  That is, it only works for signers with no clientUserID.  But with no clientUserID, I can't use embedded signing.

Has anyone got embedded Any Signers working or have a workaround?

Some further details:

1. Our process is automated and embedded-only so that we can use our own email content and provide the option of signing via email or in-application frame to our end users.
2. I've been able to get the Any Signer option working according to the DocuSign Quick Start Guide:
   https://www.docusign.com/sites/default/files/Quick%20Start%20-%20Using%20the%20Any%20Signer%20Option.pdf

   The problem is that this works only for non-embedded users.
3. I'm able to create an envelope via the REST API, with Any Signer as follows:

   ```
   POST https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/<account>/envelopes

   {
       "emailBlurb" : "Test Email Blurb",
       "emailSubject" : "Test Email Subject",
       "status" : "sent",
       "documents" : [{
               "documentId" : "1",
               "name" : "TestDoc.pdf",
           }
       ],
       "recipients" : {
           "signers" : [{
                   "recipientId" : 1,
                   "email" : "any@example.com",
                   "name" : "Any Signer",
                   "tabs" : {
                       "signHereTabs" : [{
                               "documentId" : "1",
                               "recipientId" : 1,
                               "name" : "SignHere_3",
                               "pageNumber" : 1,
                               "xPosition" : 81,
                               "yPosition" : 447,
                               "tabName" : "SignHere_3"
                           }
                       ],
                   },
                   "routingOrder" : 1,
               }
           ]
       }
   }
   ```
4. I've tried switching recipients as an alternative to Any Signer, with no luck.  Please see this (unanswered) question:

   [Switch signers on an In Process shared document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24916310/switch-signers-on-an-in-process-shared-document)

Comment: No, that is not possible. You must have a clientUserId.

Comment: Thanks Andrew.  I thought that might be the case.  Gah!  Another dead-end.

Comment: Why do you want any signer? Do you have a requirement that the signer has access to the envelope in a specific account? Or is there other requirements?

Comment: I want to delay the choice of which specific employee signs.    I'm currently forced to specify all signers at the time of envelope creation.  This causes problems because the employee is normally the last to sign and the initial employee may not be available after the other signers have signed.  Any Signer would solve this problem, because another employee could sign instead.

Comment: Most people create a "blank" recipient that just sits there waiting to be removed so the last person can be added when needed. Add the final recipient, delete the "blank" one.

Comment: I tried that, but whenever I add the final recipient, DocuSign won't include the tabs.  The final recipient is stuck in a draft-like 'created' state.  Nothing I do moves the signer to the necessary 'sent' state.  The details are in the related question I listed in further details 4.

Comment: Posted an answer over there.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Switch signers on an In Process shared document](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24916310/switch-signers-on-an-in-process-shared-document)

Answer (score 0):

The "any signer" feature is similar to a Distribution Group in your mail. It sends the email to all these people and any one of them can sign. When you use embedded signing, you have to specific who is the signer before you can generate the URL for the embedded signing session. This means you cannot use a signing group, but you have to have a specific signer (email and name) that would be used in that session.